# get the value of confirm dialog box in UIWebView

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, iphone, uiwebview

Good Evening,

Can we detect the confirm dialog box appearing in website loaded in UIWebView. If any know how to handle in `UIWebView` Delegate method. Given below code written in the source file i viewed in website.

```
<span>
 <input type="submit" id="cancel" value="Cancel" name="cancel" style="display: none;" /><a
  href="#" onclick="return Cancel();" tabindex="8" class="cancel_link">Cancel</a>
  </span>
 function Cancel() 
 {
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to exit? Your purchase has not completed. Click Cancel to return to WebPAY. Click OK to return to the merchant site.')) 
     {
        $('#cancel').click();
        return true;
      }
    return false;
 }
```

How can i get the value in `UIWebView` delegate methods?

i need to check `onclick="return Cancel();`where as it is generating the confirm dialog box

Answer (score 0):

So you want to message Cocoa from Javascript, right? The easiest way to do that is to open a URL with a custom URL scheme from Javascript. Then in

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

you can catch this URL request and do whatever you like in Cocoa. If you want to pass parameters you could send those along in the URL request, too.

To make things easier, there's a nice framework: https://github.com/ochameau/NativeBridge